# Simulating different client resolutions

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010, dreamweaver

Is there any way to make a preview of our template in other monitors like 14 or 15 inch monitors ?

Is there any simulator program ? I want to check that there is no horizontal scroll on screen when my web site opens .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty quick way to test a bunch of different device viewports
http://www.benjaminkeen.com/misc/bricss/
Best of all - You can define your own viewport sizes.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to check that there is no horizontal scroll on screen when my web site opens .

There are several browser plugins that will simulate a resolution change by resizing the browser window. [Window Resizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/window-resizer/) is one for Firefox.

Other than that, you can change your monitor's resolution to test what a site looks like on other screens. (What counts is the [screen resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_resolution), not monitor size.)

Comment: This was good advice, but the firefox plugin is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

[ResizeMyBrowser](http://resizemybrowser.com/) is my go-to for this - I just keep it open in one tab and whatever I'm working on in another, and it's easy to see all the options 'live'.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for testing your site on different resolutions is [Sizer](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/)

No problems with resizing all modern browsers (32 and 64bit Windows), even their 64bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now has a native developer feature that supports resizing the viewport: Open the Firefox command line with `Shift` + `F2`, then type "resize on". Now you have a frame within the former viewport that can be shifted to the extents of your desire. You can also call a certain viewport size by entering "resize to  ".